# touchscreen goes to sleep after idle

Tags: windows, drivers, touchscreen, touch

Recently i bought a new lenovo flex 5 with windows 11 preinstalled. I noticed that the touchscreen goes to sleep after a few seconds of leaving it idle. When i use it continuously, it works flawlessly. To me it seems strongly like a driver is going to sleep. Unfortunately, I have no idea whether this is a problem soley to lenovo devices.

I tried almost everything that i've found on the internet:

- I turned off all the "allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" in the device manager
- uninstalled the drivers
- multiple hard resets
- multiple power cycles
- Bios update

I don't think that this is caused by a loose connector, as it works fine while actively using it. I am genuinely curious of what this could be. I think i've exhausted all the software related fixes.
The only thing I can think of is:

- a touchscreen controller not working right
- it is internally wired through some HDMI-Port that isn't proprely working

Thanks a lot, i really appreciate any input

Comment: I had that issue with my Lenovo X13.  I had to update Power Drivers a couple of times. video drivers. do all Windows 11 Updates, and a BIOS update to get reasonable time. I have do another BIOS update since.

Comment: does it work reliably now?

Comment: Yes, fairly reliable now. Not perfect but workable.

Comment: with the power drivers, do you mean the lenovo power management driver?

Comment: Lenovo have great updates app ( compared to most other competitors ). Just Download Lenovo Vantage from MS Store and run the driver update wizard. You should do that to most new devices, especially when you're experiencing a problem with them. Good luck!

Comment: Yes power drivers

Comment: thanks both of you, i'll try it out.

Comment: unfortunately, i had no luck with it.

Comment: few hours ago, a lenovo technician came by and replaced the screen. unfortunately, this did not help either